# Adding captions to both the top and bottom of a pandas style object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I am trying to add captions to my style object (a pandas dataframe). Adding one caption is fine (to either the bottom or top), but it won't let me add both. When I try changing the both captions, the last argument just overrides the first (aka wont let me add captions to both the top and bottom of my table at the same time)

```py
df.set_caption("Table title.")\
 .set_table_styles([{
     'selector': 'caption',
     'props': 'caption-side: top; font-size:1.25em;'
 }], overwrite=False).set_caption("Notes for the Bottom of the Table.")\
 .set_table_styles([{
     'selector': 'caption',
     'props': 'caption-side: bottom; font-size:1.25em;'
 }], overwrite=False)
```

Comment: provide input and output  samples.

Comment: I guess it can be any data frame object and it should have a caption on top AND at the bottom. Quite clear imho

Comment: "A [TABLE](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TABLE) element may only contain one [CAPTION](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-CAPTION) element." [source](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.2). This is a feature of HTML not pandas. If you provided a sample DataFrame as well as what you _want_ these multiple captions to look like there is likely to be a workaround, but as it stands you cannot do what you're looking to do.

Comment: For example...sample df below...

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=["A", "B"])

then covert it to a styler object...

df.style

my question is how do i get 2 captions (1 on the top of the table, 1 on the bottom of the table?). Let's say caption 1 reads "This is a Tile" and caption 2 reads "notes for the table"

Comment: Since tables cannot have two captions, as @HenryEcker states, it leaves you with using one caption (which is placed at bottom) and either subcalssing the Styler object as explained in the docs with a heading, or getting the HTML result, via `styler.to_html`, and manually insterting a new HTML `<h2>` or `<p>` element between `</style>` and `<table>` to give the effect you are looking for.

Comment: thank you very much will try that